# Python dryscrape "Xvfb does not start" under XQuartz & xvfbwrapper & MacOSX Sierra

Tags: python, xquartz, dryscrape

Under MacOSX Sierra, and XQuartz 2.7.11, Python 2.7.  I was able to install dryscrape and its required other python packages.  I've tried quite a few methods to get some simple code working, but I can't seem to get it working.  Here is the simple code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#coding: utf-8
import dryscrape
testurl = 'http://avi.im/stuff/js-or-no-js.html'
dryscrape.start_xvfb()
session = dryscrape.Session()
session.visit(testurl)
exit()
```

You can see it is a simple python script file.  It fails on either the `start_svfb()` or the `Session()` line.  I can post the errors and such, but can I start a discussion on simply what check list should I setup, run, and test to make sure the X11 environment is right?  Do I run the script under OS X terminal or XQuartz?  What am I missing?  etc.?

Thanks in advance, Lucas.

here is the last traceback from python:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./fred.py", line 19, in

```
session = dryscrape.Session()
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/dryscrape/session.py", line 22, in __init__

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/dryscrape/driver/webkit.py", line 30, in __init__

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/webkit_server-1.0-py2.7.egg/webkit_server.py", line 230, in __init__
self.conn = connection or ServerConnection()

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/webkit_server-1.0-py2.7.egg/webkit_server.py", line 507, in __init__
self._sock = (server or get_default_server()).connect()

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/webkit_server-1.0-py2.7.egg/webkit_server.py", line 450, in get_default_server
_default_server = Server()

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/webkit_server-1.0-py2.7.egg/webkit_server.py", line 416, in __init__
stderr = subprocess.PIPE)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you sure you have xvfbwrapper installed? Also please post your errors.

Comment: yes, I believe all of the packages, including xvfbwrapper is installed:

lucas$ sudo pip install dryscrape
Requirement already satisfied: dryscrape in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dryscrape-1.0-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied: webkit_server>=1.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/webkit_server-1.0-py2.7.egg (from dryscrape)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml-3.7.3-py2.7-macosx-10.12-intel.egg (from dryscrape)
Requirement already satisfied: xvfbwrapper in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from dryscrape)